# How to return 2d array from a method when it's size is dynamic?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hi i have following piece of code, here i have to return data which store in array `s[][]` from this function, Please help how i can do it.

```
 public static String[][] readxl(String filepath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int rowcount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            Row row1 = sheet.getRow(0);
            int colcount=row1.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            String[][]s = new String[rowcount][colcount];
            for(int i=0;i<sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();i++)
            {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                for(int j=0; j<row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();j++)
                {
                    Cell c = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
                    int celltype = c.getCellType();
                    if(celltype==1)
                    {
                        s[i][j] =c.getStringCellValue();               
                    }
                    if(celltype==0)
                    {   
                        s[i][j] =String.valueOf((int)c.getNumericCellValue()); 
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: If its dynamic don't use arrays, use `Collection` (`ArrayList` of `ArrayList` (2D) for example); Arrays = Fixed size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use

```
return s;
```

There is no problem in returning an array even if size is dynamic.

Good luck.